# Get infinity when dividing by zero

Tags: python

Is it possible to assign say infinity to something divided by `0` instead of it throwing `ZeroDivisionError`?

Like a function that assigns infinity to `something/0`.

Comment: Use `math.inf`.

Comment: Either Check the value of the divisor first and if its 0 dont try the division just return some other value to represent what you want. Otherwise you can use pythons try/exception blocks to catch ZeroDivision error and return something else

Comment: but how exactly do I assign it in the program?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] so that we can better understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want a float that represents infinity, you can issue `float('inf')` or `float('-inf')`.

---

Standard Python floats and ints will give you a `ZeroDivisionError`, but you can use `numpy` datatypes.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.float64(15)/0
inf
```

---

Without `numpy`, write a function:

```
def my_div(dividend, divisor):
    try:
        return dividend/divisor
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        if dividend == 0:
            raise ValueError('0/0 is undefined')
            # instead of raising an error, an alternative
            # is to return float('nan') as the result of 0/0

        if dividend > 0:
            return float('inf')
        else:
            return float('-inf')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [numpy.float64()](https://kite.com/python/docs/numpy.float64).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.float64(1.0) / 0.0
Inf
```

This will not trow an error, but a warning. You can control [warnings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) using the built-in warnings module

Answer (score 0):

you can either use python try except blocks or you can check the value of the divisor first and use an else case.

```py
from math import inf
a = 5
b = 0
try:
    x = a / b
except ZeroDivisionError as zde:
    x = inf

if b:
    y = a / b
else:
    y = inf


print(x)
print(y)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
inf
inf
```

Comment: Just to note, you don't need the `math` module. `math.inf` is the same value as `float('inf')`.

Comment: @timgeb In which way? if i try with `a=-10` and `b=2` the output of x and y is `-5.0` which i think is the correct answer

Comment: `-10/0` -> `-inf`, `0/0` undefined.

Comment: The limit could be infinity or negative infinity, depending on the sign of `a` and the direction from which you approach 0. The limit does not exist at all when `a == 0`.

Comment: ah i just wrote a base case as all the OP said is if its divide by 0 return inf.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you can use `math.inf` from *math* module.

You can catch a ZeroDivision error like this:

```
from math import inf

try:
    x = 5/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    x = inf
```